# count mongodb in php

Tags: php, mongodb, count

I have a collection user which has 2 parameters (Username,paid), username is a string and paid is a string too, i should count how many users with the parameter paid="true"

this is my try

```
<?php

$connection = new MongoClient();
$collection = $connection->Ahmed->user;

$cursor = $collection->find();
var_dump($collection->count());
var_dump($collection->count($cursor->paid=>"true")));
?>
```

if there is an expert in mongo could help, thanks :)

Answer (score 11):

The new driver does not implement  `$cursor->count()` use `$collection->count()` instead

```
$collection->count($filter)
```

in your case: `$filter = array('paid' => 'true')`

Comment: Excuse me, but what do you meaning if I'm using `$this->collection`?

Comment: My PHP Mongo Library is 1.7.

Comment: How to use count on mongodb php aggregate

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$connection = new MongoClient();
$collection = $connection->Ahmed->user;
$cursor = $collection->find();

var_dump(count($cursor->toArray()));
?>
```

I hope can help you

Answer (score -3):

First you need to tell mongo what you intend to find in the `find()` function. Then it will return a cursor to the result set, which you can call `count()` on.

```
<?php

$connection = new MongoClient();
$collection = $connection->Ahmed->user;

$cursor = $collection->find(array("paid"=>"true"));
var_dump($cursor->count()); //return the total count of documents with "paid" equal to "true"
```

Comment: This will work with the older PHP mongo driver, not the new one.

Answer (score -3):

You can simply convert your response into array using **iterator_to_array** then count array records in php.

```
<?php

$connection = new MongoClient();
$collection = $connection->Ahmed->user;

$cursor = $collection->find();
var_dump(count(iterator_to_array($cursor)));
?>
```